# Touchscreen not found on notebook using Lubuntu

Tags: lubuntu, touchscreen

Lubuntu (and any other Linux distro) cannot recognize the touchscreen on my Trekstor Primebook C11 although it works well with Windows

I would be very grateful any help!

Thank you!

Comment: There was a [bug report sometime ago on Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1793044), that was first confirmed and then closed because there was no activity. [On this forum](https://forum.ubuntuusers.de/topic/trekstor-primebook-c11-fuer-ubuntu-geeignet/#post-8971348) they solved it with [this unofficial driver](https://github.com/AliciaHormann/publicStuff) (!kernel compile!), but it does not look like there is any [official driver from the manufacturer](http://www.trekstor.de/products/notebook-and-2in1.html). The model 11 is not even listed anymore on their website.

Comment: You haven't said what release of Lubuntu.  Other linux distros are off-topic here (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic) unless Ubuntu and official flavors of Ubuntu, and the age of your touchscreen chipset & age of kernel & software stack play a huge part in support.

Comment: `ubuntu-touch` is a phone OS.  Ubuntu-touch (now supported by UBports) is a different OS to Lubuntu.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_Touch

Comment: could you please help me perform the steps mentioned it this repo:
https://github.com/AliciaHormann/publicStuff
Thank you very much!!